# Avoid shutting down an entire data flow network when one block is faulted

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I am using [DataFlowEx](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx) and am wondering how I can avoid shutting down an entire DataFlow if an exception is thrown.

I have a system where tasks will come in at random times, and I want the network to log failures, abandon that particular task and continue with execution of the others.

In reading the documentation on both TPL and DataFlowEx, specifically things like

> It [a faulted block] should decline any further incoming messages. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/11/09/exception-handling-in-tpl-dataflow-networks/)
>
> DataflowEx takes a fast-fail approach on exception handling just like
>   TPL Dataflow. When an exception is thrown, the low-level block ends to
>   the Faulted state first. Then the Dataflow instance who is the parent
>   of the failing block gets notified. It will immediately propagate the
>   fatal error: notify its other children to shutdown immediately. After
>   all its children is done/completed, the parent Dataflow also comes to
>   its completion, with the original exception wrapped in the
>   CompletionTask whose status is also Faulted. [Here](https://github.com/gridsum/DataflowEx)

It almost seems like a block moving on from a failure is not intended...

My flows include a lot of File IO and i am expecting the occasional exception to occur (network volumes going offline during read/write, connection failures, permission issues...)

I don't want the entire pipeline to die.

Here is an example of the code I'm working with:

```
using Gridsum.DataflowEx;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace DataManagementSystem.Data.Pipeline.Actions
{
    class CopyFlow : Dataflow<FileInfo, FileInfo>
    {
        private TransformBlock<FileInfo, FileInfo> Copier;
        private string destination;

        public CopyFlow(string destination) : base(DataflowOptions.Default)
        {
            this.destination = destination;

            Copier = new TransformBlock<FileInfo, FileInfo>(f => Copy(f));

            RegisterChild(Copier);            
        }

        public override ITargetBlock<FileInfo> InputBlock { get { return Copier; } }

        public override ISourceBlock<FileInfo> OutputBlock { get { return Copier; } }

        protected virtual FileInfo Copy(FileInfo file)
        {
            try
            {
                return file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destination, file.Name));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //Log the exception
                //Abandon this unit of work
                //resume processing subsequent units of work
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm sending work to the pipeline:

```
var result = pipeline.ProcessAsync(new[] { file1, file2 }).Result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block will become faulted if it throws an `Exception`. If you do not want the pipeline to fail you can either not propagate completion or handle the `Exception`. Handling the exception can take many forms but it sounds like all you need is a simple retry. You could use a `try/catch` and implement your own retry loop or use something like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). A simple example is shown below.

```
public BuildPipeline() {
    var waitTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<IOException>()
                            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, i => waitTime);
    var fileIOBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(async fileName => await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await FileIOAsync(fileName)));
}
```

Note: this code was not tested but should get you in the right direction.

**Edit**

You almost have everything you need. Once you catch the exception and log it you can return null or some other marker that you can filter out of the pipeline to a `NullTarget`. This code ensures that the `NullTarget` filtering link is the first link on the `Copier` so any nulls don't make it to your actual destination.

```
class CopyFlow : Dataflow<FileInfo, FileInfo> {
    private TransformBlock<FileInfo, FileInfo> Copier;
    private string destination;

    public CopyFlow(string destination) : base(DataflowOptions.Default) {
        this.destination = destination;

        Copier = new TransformBlock<FileInfo, FileInfo>(f => Copy(f));
        Copier.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<FileInfo>(), info => info == null);

        RegisterChild(Copier);
    }

    public override ITargetBlock<FileInfo> InputBlock { get { return Copier; } }

    public override ISourceBlock<FileInfo> OutputBlock { get { return Copier; } }

    protected virtual FileInfo Copy(FileInfo file) {
        try {
            return file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destination, file.Name));
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            //Log the exception
            //Abandon this unit of work
            //resume processing subsequent units of work
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What your saying is interesting, specifically about "handling the exception". Say rather than retrying, I wanted to just log the failure and stop that work unit altogether. Specifically my problem is that once inside the function that *actually* does the work, I can't figure out how to: catch the exception -> log the error -> abandon that unit of work -> continue as if nothing happened. The problem is the function caller is expecting a `FileInfo` back once the function returns.

Comment: I see now. My confusion stemmed from me not fully understanding the use of `NullTarget`. I'll read up on it, thanks so much!. P.S. Polly looks absolutely brilliant! I am going to start using right away, exactly what I needed (and would have implemented myself, rather crudely).